# How do I use FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter

Tags: apache-nifi

I my Nifi controller I want to configure the `FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter`, but I have no Idea what I should put in the `"Text"` field.  I'm getting the text from my source (in my case `GetSolr`), and just want to write this, period.
Documentation and mailinglist do not seem to tell me how this is done, any help appreciated.

**EDIT: Here the sample input + output I want to achieve (as you can see: not ransformation needed, plain text, no JSON input)**

**EDIT: I now realize, that I can't tell GetSolr to return just CSV data - but I have to use Json** 
So referencing with attribute seems to be fine.  What the documentation omits is, that the ${flowFile} attribute should containt the complete flowfile that is returned.

Sample input:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "zkConnected": true,
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "q": "*:*",
      "_": "1553686715465"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 3194,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "{402EBE69-0000-CD1D-8FFF-D07756271B4E}",
        "MimeType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        "FileName": "Test.docx",
        "DateLastModified": "2019-03-27T08:05:00.103Z",
        "_version_": 1629145864291221504,
        "LAST_UPDATE": "2019-03-27T08:16:08.451Z"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Wanted output

```
{402EBE69-0000-CD1D-8FFF-D07756271B4E}
```

**BTW: The documentation says this:**

> The text to use when writing the results. This property will evaluate the Expression Language using any of the fields available in a Record.
>   Supports Expression Language: true (will be evaluated using flow file attributes and variable registry)

I want to use my source's text, so I'm confused

Answer (score 3):

You need to use expression language as if the record's fields are the FlowFile's attributes. 
Example:

Input:

```
{
  "t1": "test",
  "t2": "ttt",
  "hello": true,
  "testN": 1
}
```

`Text` property in `FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter`:

```
${t1} k!${t2} ${hello}:boolean

${testN}Num
```

Output(using `ConvertRecord`):

```
test k!ttt true:boolean

1Num
```

EDIT:

Seems like what you needed was reading from Solr and write a single column csv. You need to use `CSVRecordSetWriter`. As for the same, 
I should tell you to consider to upgrade to 1.9.1. Starting from 1.9.0, the schema can be inferred for you.

otherwise, you can set `Schema Access Strategy` as `Use 'Schema Text' Property`
then, use the following schema in Schema Text

```
{
  "name": "MyClass",
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.acme.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "int"
    }
  ]
}
```

this should work
I'll edit it into my answer. If it works for you, please choose my answer :)

Comment: sorry, I just realized, that I have to put in input + wanted output - I don't have json as input, I could create json as input, but it seems overly complicated...

Comment: It really doesn't matter what the input is. It could be a Json, avro or whatever you want. The field names are still the same so you can use them the same..

Comment: Now I see that you want the same output as your input.. What is the processor you are using? Why would you want the same output?

Comment: I'm using a GetSolr processer, and want it to return me CSV-Data, with only one column, wich is the "id".  This should return just a line-by-line input, that I just want to put in the flowfiles.

Comment: So why not just use `CSVRecordSetWriter`?

Comment: Because I need a schema registry. Another thing that has to work... I seem to need that for the FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter, too... I'm gettin an error like that "SchemaNotFoundException: Cannot inherit Schema from Record because no schema was found:
13:36:07 CETERRORbe2ac0a8-0169-1000-bfc7-4dbab1c914f1
GetSolr[id=be2ac0a8-0169-1000-bfc7-4dbab1c914f1] Failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.schema.access.SchemaNotFoundException: Cannot inherit Schema from Record because no schema was found: ....

Comment: Which version of NiFi do you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190769/discussion-between-ben-yaakobi-and-frischling).